# Looking for master-detail (hierarchical) control for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, controls

I'm looking for such control in order to represent a hierarchical list that I can sort separately each set of master (parents) and his details. Something like that:
http://www.microsoft.com/Global/project/en/us/PublishingImages/ProjPortServ-scrn-2-lrg.jpg

I think that such a control does not provided in .NET
Do you know for a good 3rd-party for such purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a combination of a `TreeView` and a `ListView`. There are various articles about this on codeproject, including this one: [Virtual Mode TreeListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/VirtualModeTreeListView.aspx)

The screenshot looks similar to your screenshot at least.